# Use of undeclared type 'PostTableViewCell'

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error.

I've attached two pieces of code below, any help is very appreciated

```
    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell <--- error is with this line
    let post = self.posts![indexPath.row]
    let user = post["user"] as? PFUser
    let caption = post["caption"] as! String?

    if let photo = post["media"] {
        let imagePFFIle = photo as! PFFile
        imagePFFIle.getDataInBackground(block: {(imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    cell.photoView.image = image
                    cell.usernameLabel.text = user?.username
                    cell.usernameLabel2.text = user?.username
                    cell.captionLabel.text = caption
                }
            }
        })
    }
    //print("Image exists - Home View Controller")
    //print("\(posts!.count)")
    return cell
}
```

classes from Main.storyboard

```
 <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" restorationIdentifier="" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" reuseIdentifier="postCell" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QKL-F5-RQ0" customClass="PostTableViewCell">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="71" width="375" height="596"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        </tableView>
```

Comment: Yes, I do in PostTableViewCell.swift

Comment: @Sh_Khan can you attach the definition of PostTableViewCell ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `PostTableViewCell` isn't part of the right target. Select the file in the navigator, open the right pain and select File Inspector. Make sure that the main target is checked. See example below:[image]